# Passing one Dimension of a Two Dimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have moved from C to C#.
I have a function which accepts an array. I want to pass one dimension of a Two Dimensional array to this function.

C Code would be:-

```
void array_processing(int * param); 

void main()
{
  int Client_ID[3][50];
  /* Some 
     Processing 
     which fills 
     this array */
    array_processing(&Client_ID[1]);
}
```

Now, When I want to do same in C#, How can I pass this array?
Function defination will look like:-

```
private void array_processing(ref int[] param);
```

and Array would be declared as :-

```
int[,] Client_ID = new int[3,50];
```

Now How can I pass `Client_ID[1]` to the function `array_processing()`??

By doing `array_processing ( ref Client_ID[1])` shouts as "Wrong Number of Indices"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really do that. C# is less outgoing about its arrays, and prevents you from doing C-like manipulations. This is a good thing.

You have various options:

1. Create a 1D array and copy your 2D row to it.
2. Use a jagged array - an array of arrays, which is more like what C lets you do.
3. Have an array_processing overload that takes a 2D array and a row number.
4. If you *really* want to access a 2D row as a 1D array, you should create a 'RowProxy' class that will implement the IList interface and let you access just one row:

   ```
   class RowProxy<T>: IList<T>
   {
       public RowProxy(T[,] source, int row)
       { 
          _source = source;
          _row = row;
       }

       public T this[int col]
       {
           get { return _source[_row, col]; } 
           set { _source[_row, col] = value; }
       }

       private T[,] _source;
       private int _row;

       // Implement the rest of the IList interface
   }
   ```
5. Use a lambda expression that will lose the array semantics, but is rather cool:

   ```
   var ClientId = ...;

   var row_5_accessor = (c=>ClientId[5, c]);
   ```

   You can use row_5_accessor as a function, `row_5_accessor(3)` will give you `ClientId[5, 3]`

Comment: Now that gone Way above my brain for Novice like me!! Will try one by one.... But this C# disappointed me... It just can't pass Multidimensional array! C Rocks!!:)

Comment: No, no, you can pass a multidimensional array without a problem. Treating a multidimensional array as a vector is not possible. On the other hand, nothing in C gives you anywhere near the flexibility of my suggestions 4 and 5.

Comment: Ohhkay!! Thanks Buddy!! And Yes, 4th & 5th are really good! Thanks again!

Comment: @zmbq: You say "This is a good thing". Why? What's so good about restricting the syntax in this way? Could unsafe code get around this?

Comment: C multidimensional arrays are extremely confusing. If you have a 3x3 matrix: `int a[3][3]`, what's the type of a[2] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jagged array

```
// Initialize jagged array
int[][] clientID = new int[3][];
for (int i=0; i<clientId.Length; i++)
{
   clientId[i] = new int[50];
}

array_processing(ref clientId[1]);
```

And your method:

```
private void array_processing(ref int[] subArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare method

```
private void ParseArray(int[,] ar)
{
    // Some work...
}
```

- UDP: Code format

Comment: he wants to pass one dimension not all matrix

Comment: But I want only One dimension get processed in function! In this case, I would need to write like, private void ParseArray(int[,]ar,int dimension) and then pass ParseArray(ref Client_ID,1)

Comment: Sorry, it was Friday evening :)

Answer (score 0):

A primitive way would be:

```
var dimNumber = 1;

int[] oneDimension = new int[50];

for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   oneDimension[i] = Client_ID[dimNumber][i];
}

array_processing ( ref oneDimension);
```

I would suggest using Lambda expressions like in the way 5 of zmbq's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare you array as

```
int[][] Client_ID = new[] { new int[50], new int[50], new int[50] };
```

and then you can pass it to your array_processing function

```
array_processing(ref Clinet_ID[1]);
```

Sorry for miss of my pen.

Comment: First, Multidimensional arrays couldn't be declared as this and I tried the same but it gave error as "Wrong Number of Indices". I mentioned this in question.

Comment: sorry, I've changed the declaration, you could use the notation above

Answer (score 0):

Late to the conversation, but here is a jagged array example to do this:

```
string[][] rows = GetStringArray(values);
string[] row = rows[0];
```

You would set up your jagged array something like:

```
// rowCount from runtime data
stringArray = new string[rowCount][];

for (int index = 0; index < rowCount; index++)
{
    // columnCount from runtime data
    stringArray[index] = new string[columnCount];

    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < columnCount; index2++)
    {
        // value from runtime data
        stringArray[index][index2] = value;
    }
}
```