# Lambda expressions for arrays?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, binding, lambda

After reading this question here: [Passing one Dimension of a Two Dimensional Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530773/passing-one-dimension-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c-sharp/9530888#comment12075209_9530888), I wondered whether it's possible to use some C# 4 trickery to bind one index of a multidimensional array. Hopefully something like this:

```
var matrix = new int[10, 20];
var row = <some dynamic magic with matrix, 7>;
```

And have row being semantically identical to matrix[7] - so that row[4] is exactly matrix[7, 4].

It's quite easy to do with functions:

```
int some_func(int a, string b);
var some_func_5 = (b=>some_func(5, b));
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: So function you mentioned is not good enough?

Comment: No, the function loses the Array semantics altogether. It's not enumerable and doesn't have an indexer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything particularly C#-4-specific here. I'd personally build a specific type for it:

```
public sealed class RectangularArrayView<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly int row;
    private readonly T[,] array;

    public RectangularArrayView(int row, T[,] array)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.array = array;
    }

    public T this[int column]
    {
        get { return array[row, column]; }
        set { array[row, column] = value; }
    }

    // etc for other IList<T> methods; use explicit interface implementation
    // for things like Add which don't make sense on arrays
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have done, but I was hoping there's a neat trick I missed - implementing all those IList methods is a pain. Now I'm wondering how would I like this language feature to look like, if it existed.

Comment: @zmbq: It feels like a very niche requirement for a language feature. Don't forget that if you used jagged arrays instead, you could just use `array[row]` and get a 1-D array back...

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how nichey it is. Sure, there's no point in adding such a feature just for *this* particular use-case, but it might be useful for other things, as well. This is all too hypothetical, no point in discussing how a non-existing language feature can be useful in unknown situations...