# Copy a 3-dim array into an 11x3-dim array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, copy

I have this C# code which has a 3-dim double and then copies it into a 11x3 double:

```
var i = 8;
var temprate = new double[]{1,2,3};
var RATES = new double[11,3]

RATES[i, 0] = temprate[0];
RATES[i, 1] = temprate[1];
RATES[i, 2] = temprate[2];
```

How can I copy temprate into RATES directly (and preferably without a loop)?

i.e: `"RATES[i,*]=temprate"`

Comment: Please include a language tag. To get experts in your language tag your question correctly. Also, you are looking for for loops.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530773/passing-one-dimension-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c-sharp/9530888#9530888) is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(temprate, 0, RATES, i * 3 * sizeof(double), 3 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what exactly each part does?

Comment: @emcor, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx